# Linux: What is the best way to estimate the code & static data size of program?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I want to be able to get an estimate of how much code & static data is used by my C++ program?

Is there a way to find this out by looking at the executable or object files?  Or perhaps something I can do at runtime?

Will objdump & readelf help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"size" is the traditional tool.  "readelf" has a lot of options.

```
$ size /bin/sh
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 712739   37524   21832  772095   bc7ff /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take the next step of identifying the functions and data structures to focus on for footprint reduction, the --size-sort argument to nm can show you:

```
$ nm --size-sort /usr/bin/fld | tail -10
000000ae T FontLoadFontx
000000b0 T CodingByRegistry
000000b1 t ShmFont
000000ec t FontLoadw
000000ef T LoadFontFile
000000f6 T FontLoadDFontx
00000108 D fSRegs
00000170 T FontLoadMinix
000001e7 T main
00000508 T FontLoadBdf
```

Answer (score 1):

`readelf` will indeed help. You can use the `-S` option; that will show the sizes of all sections. `.text` is (the bulk of) your executable code. `.data` and `.rodata` is your static data. There are other sections too, some of which are used at runtime, others only at link time.

Answer (score 1):

```
size -A
```